# How to add dynamic date to foundation 2 emails?

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email, yaml-front-matter

I am trying to add dynamic month and year to my foundation email template. I have tried adding the year in a test file - `year.js` in `/src/helpers/` as shown here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/37160-insert-current-yeardate-in-html

but it doesn't work when I mention `{{year}}`.

My code is:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

Wondering if I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix just after posting this. All you have to do is stop watching `CMD/Ctrl + C` re-start your npm server `npm start` and it works the way it's supposed to.